# Referencing problem with hyperref and refsection in a draft with global and local areas?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I have a 4-page document with a global and a local areas. The pages #1 and #3 are the main text and page #4 is the reference section (pages #1, #2, #3 are the global area). The page #2 is a local area (with a local reference section) within the draft. Everything with this local area is fine. The local referencing works ok (hyperref correctly point citation to its reference, thanks to refsection).
The problem is with the main draft. The issue is when I click to the references in the main document (whether in page 1 or 3) it jumps to the first page of the document (instead of jumping to the page #4).
I made this 4-page example document to discuss this issue and hopefully find a solution for it. I believe it is related to hyperref and biblatex packages. I read multiple related posts also the biblatex documentation without success.

p.s. I have used refsection in the global reference section because I wanted to have separate sections of references (i.e., journals, conferences, etc)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

% page #1
\begin{center} 
\textbf{\LARGE Main area}
\end{center}
This is the main area of the draft. This is the first reference \cite{authorA} 

% page #2
\pagebreak
\begin{refsection}
\begin{center} 
\textbf{\LARGE Local area}
\end{center}    
This is the local area of the draft. The local reference \cite{authorB}. 

\nocite{authorB}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

% page #3
\pagebreak
Continuation of the main draft... This is the second reference \cite{authorC}

% page #4
\pagebreak
\section*{Publications}

\subsection*{journals}
\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword={jour}]

\subsection*{conferences}
\printbibliography[heading=none, keyword={conf}]

\end{document}
```

Here are the entries of the .bib file.

```
@Article{authorA,
    author    = {author A},
    title     = {Tiltle A},
    pages     = {1--2},
    volume    = {1},
    journal   = {Journal Name},
    keywords  = {jour},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    year      = {2000},
}

@Article{authorB,
    author    = {author B},
    title     = {Tiltle B},
    pages     = {1--2},
    volume    = {1},
    journal   = {Journal Name},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    year      = {2000},
}

@Article{authorC,
    author    = {author C},
    title     = {Tiltle C},
    pages     = {1--2},
    volume    = {1},
    journal   = {Journal Name},
    keywords  = {conf},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    year      = {2000},
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: well what do you expect to happen? You have no bibliography outside the refsection and so the \cite commands can't jump anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I oversimplified the question. It is modified now. I have used refsection at the end because I wanted to have separate sections for references (i.e., journals, conferences, etc).

Comment: I assume that you actually don't want refsection, but should add a filter to printbibliography.

Comment: Thanks for showing the direction. I'll check and learn the filter capabilities.

Comment: I followed this article, and now everything is fine: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibliography_management_with_biblatex
The question is also modified to produce the correct behavior.